# What are the Changes to sun SCJP/SCJA/SCEA tracks since oracle took over?

Tags: java, oracle, scjp

**The Context:**

It appears that the simple scjp ->scja->.... tracks for sun certification have been merged with other oracle style certifications... As a developer, I've spent some time lately trying to figure out the new "pathways" for certification.

**Existing Resources:**

There is a very dense, but also informative Page here : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun_Certified_Professional  The Oracle website is also, of course, full of links and diagrams with different certification factoids.

**My Problem:**

It's not clear that there is a new paradigm or pathway for java certifications is emerging, and thus whether or not the old SCJP style certifications are still in existence (albeit with a different title), nor is it clear what the entire certification pipeline looks like : for example, this diagram (from the older sun certifications) http://www.whizlabs.com/images/jwhiz.png, clearly related the myriad of certification and training initiatives in a lucid and easily interpreted diagram. But I don't see any such resource for explaining and comparing the modern Oracle Java certifications.

**The Question(s):**

What is the relationship between the new Oracle certifications? And how do they relate to the original SCJP, SCJD, and SCEA exams?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There wasn't a lot of changes after the Sun acquisition. The exam topics remained as they were (well, there were slight changes because of the migration from Prometric to Perason VUE certification platform - no drag & drop questions anymore).

The pipeline remains the same. If you want to know what prerequisites are required, just enter the [Oracle Certification Program](http://education.oracle.com/pls/web_prod-plq-dad/db_pages.getpage?page_id=140) and look for interesting certificate.

Exemplary prerequisites are shown [here](http://education.oracle.com/pls/web_prod-plq-dad/db_pages.getpage?page_id=320) (for Java SE 6 Programmer). It shows that no prerequisites are required to take this exam.

The only required prerequisite for following certificates (beside the Associate level) is the **Oracle Certified Professional Java Programmer**. Every other certificate (JSP & Servlets, EJB, Developer, Enterprise Architect, WebServices) can be taken after achieving the OCPJP.

However, some time ago Oracle introduced additional prerequisites for Master exams (that is **Oracle Certified Master Developer** & **Enterprise Architect**). To take it you need to pass some courses (and of course pay a lot for them). Until that time, in order to take OCMJD and OCMJEA (formerly known as SCJD and SCEA) just SCJP/OCPJP was required.

**EDIT:**

Forgot to add - the *Sun Certified Web Component Developer* was splitted into:
- Oracle Certified Expert JSP and Servlet Developer and,
- Oracle Certified Expert Web Services developer.

The *Sun Certified EJB Developer* was splitted into:
- Oracle Certified Expert Enterprise JavaBeans Developer and,
- Oracle Certified Expert Java Persistence API Developer.

**Useful resources:**
- http://blogs.oracle.com/certification/
- http://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/SCJP-FAQ (and a lot of other certificate FAQ sections)

Answer (score 7):

The new oracle java 7 certifications don't map to the sun certifications anymore.

The old java/Java EE 5 and 6 certifications mapped one to one the oracle OCA, OCP, OCM certifications.

You can get an overview of the current certification paths at:
http://education.oracle.com/pls/web_prod-plq-dad/db_pages.getpage?page_id=140
http://education.oracle.com/pls/web_prod-plq-dad/db_pages.getpage?page_id=141#middleware

For java 7 you cannot get the OCP/SCJP without doing the OCA/SCJA first. They said they overhauled them. You may check the links on [facebook](http://www.facebook.com/javacertifiedprofessional) what they actually did.

For the old Java developer you now have to visit a classroom course.

I'm still wondering what will happen to the special expert certifications.

Comment: Yes but clearly, they serve a similar purpose and cover similar content --- and they are still hierarchical.  Can you elaborate on the new paradigm ?

Comment: Well, they said the overhauled them. I'm not sure if they just want to squeeze out more money though. :)

Answer (score 0):

The organism is not Prometric anymore but PearsonVue